Missing rows in OptionSet when importing dataverse tables to Teams
Recently while trying to import a PowerApps solutions to Teams its started throwing up a 'No rows could be found in OptionSet' error for my DataVerse tables.
Error Message
I never used to have this issue, it started a few months ago but seems to happen to all my tables now.
From my understanding option sets relate to choice columns but most of my tables don't have any choice columns except the auto generated columns.
Has anyone else experienced this?
My current work around is to disconnect the tables from the app, import the solution without any tables then recreate the tables in Teams and add them back into the app but this isn't sustainable.
I've tried all the standard ways of looking for and adding dependencies but I can't find any OptionSets anywhere.
Any Ideas?
ScreenShot of 'Status Reason' column properties

This error can occur if the tables in your Dataverse environment contain fields that are configured to use OptionSets, but the required data for these OptionSets is missing.
To troubleshoot this issue, you can review the tables in your Dataverse environment and identify any fields that are configured to use OptionSets. Ensure that these OptionSets have the necessary options defined. Also, check if the data in the OptionSet fields is populated correctly. If the required data is missing, you may encounter the error when importing the solution to Teams.

Thank you!
Am I right in thinking OptionSets only relate to choice columns?
If so, the only 2 choice columns are the auto generated 'Status' and 'Status Reason'.
Looking at 'Status Reason' it's linked to status so I'm guessing it's that column (added screen shot of properties above).
It already has one default choice so do i just add an extra choice in?

Could you please try adding and check if that helps?

Hi I did try adding in 2 extra choices each for active and inactive but no joy.
Any idea where I can find any OptionSets? I still can't find them

OptionSets in Dataverse are used to create a list of options that users can select from a dropdown list in fields within tables. These OptionSets are stored as a separate table in Dataverse and are linked to the main table using a foreign key relationship.
